# How to fix Azure functions: Incompatible Node.js version (v16.4.1)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've read thru the  [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#javascript-function-basics) and created a new azure function with the VS Code extension just using the boilerplate code it spits out.

Then I set this up locally in local.settings.json (I'm on Windows)

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "~16"
  }
}
```

But I still get that node version is an incompatible error.

Comment: Did it work with node v14 ?  May be the latest node version has an issue. For local debugging the official doc says to add [this entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#local-debugging)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran it did work with v14. Then when I deployed confirmation window popped up saying I was deploying version 4. confusing.

Comment: Try removing other npm versions and just install v16

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran im using nvm so when I switch to 16 or any other that's the only one installed on PATH

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your `Function core tools` version and `Function Run time version` should be **4.***.

[image]

If the version are not 4.*. install the Function Core Tools latest version check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Cnode%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) & install required version of `node js` if you are using **windows** the version should be (**16.9.1**) for **Linux** you can use (**16.13.0**)

> Azure Functions support for Node.js 16.x is now in public preview in Azure Functions runtime 4.0.
> Node.js 16.13.0, the current LTS version, is available on Linux function apps. Windows function apps currently support version 16.9.1 and will be updated to an LTS version in December 2021. Refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-nodejs-16-in-azure-functions/)

Check your `settings.json` file targeting **projectRuntime** has **~4** and **projectLanguage** has **javascript**

```
{
"azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
"azureFunctions.postDeployTask": "npm install (functions)",
"azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "JavaScript",
"azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
"debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
"azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "npm prune (functions)"
}
```

[image]

Comment: I upvoted but not sure if this is the solution since I somehow fixed it and moved on. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue with `Node V16.17.0 and azure function core tools V4*`

I used command to trace logs

```
func host start --verbose
```

Then I saw in logs that it's trying to download `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.zip` (with some version) to specific folder. In my case it was `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.2.13.0.zip`

I manually downloaded that file and extracted zip to downloads folder.

Then I sas in logs that before downloading this zip file, It is checking if this file already exists in temp folder and in users folder as well. In my case it was
`C:\Users\<UserID>\.azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle`

and
`C:\Users\UserID>\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\2.18.0`

Make sure to create folder structure as well if not present.

I just copied contents from extracted folder to this mentioned location.

It worked.