# VS Code debugging Typescript Azure Functions

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger, azure-functions-runtime

I am trying to debug an Azure Function App in VS Code. The Function App was created in VS Code like described in the [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-typescript?pivots=nodejs-model-v4). During this process a `.vscode` directory was created with the following configuration:

**.vscode/launch.json**

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Node Functions",
      "type": "node",
      "nodeVersionHint": 18,
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
  ]
}
```

**.vscode/settings.json**

```json
{
"azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
"azureFunctions.postDeployTask": "npm install (functions)",
"azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "TypeScript",
"azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
"debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
"azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "npm prune (functions)"
}
```

When I start the debugger with this configuration I get this error message:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5085 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.16.4.20366

[2023-08-16T19:33:11.815Z] [error] Incompatible Node.js version (v20.3.1). Refer to our documentation to see the Node.js versions supported by each version of Azure Functions: https://aka.ms/functions-node-versions
```

During researching this problem I found a lot of Stackoverflow threads from 2017 and 2018 like:

- [Visual Studio Code to use node version specified by NVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700432/visual-studio-code-to-use-node-version-specified-by-nvm)
- [VS Code, change NodeJS version for debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782144/vs-code-change-nodejs-version-for-debugger)
- [Why VSCode keeps using old node.js version on nvm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73301301/why-vscode-keeps-using-old-node-js-version-on-nvm)
- [Why is node version not changing in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71632879/why-is-node-version-not-changing-in-vs-code)

If I understand it correctly since then, it is supported that VS Code uses the Node.js version managed by NVM.

My default NVM version is 18.17.

**nvm list**

```
->     v18.17.1
         system
default -> 18 (-> v18.17.1)
```

I also made sure that VS Code is using the same shell as I do. Now what really throws me off is that I completely deleted Node.js version 20 via NVM.

So my question now is: Is there any other place where Node.js versions are configured in VS Code, specifically for the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70427342/how-to-fix-azure-functions-incompatible-node-js-version-v16-4-1) by Delliganesh Sevanesan and this [**MS Q & A**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1326458/azure-function-incompatible-node-js-version-%28v18-1) answer by navba-MSFT

Make sure you have installed a latest version of [**Azure Functions core tools**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows,portal,v2,bash&pivots=programming-language-typescript#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) for your OS. and Latest [**node.js version**](https://nodejs.org/en/download), I am using node version 18 like below:-

*I created one typescript function and tried checking the node and function core tools version like below:-*

```js
node --version
```

Node installation path:-

```
/c/Program Files/nodejs/node
```

[image]

```bash
func --version
```

[image]

**Nodejs installed like below:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am not sure why, but upgrading the azure-function-core-tools from 4.0.5085 -> 4.0.5198 helped. Very strange behaviour.